# Error "email has no attribute encode" sending email in python

Tags: python, email, mime

I am trying to send an email using `MIME` in python. Below is the code I am using :

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

try:
    raw_data = request.get_json()
    pwd_email_id = raw_data['email']
    log.error("Sending email to {}".format(pwd_email_id))
    recipients = pwd_email_id

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['Subject'] = 'App Registered'
    msg['From'] = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = email

    message_text = "Dear " + pwd_email_id + "\r\n\r\nYour app has been registered successfully.\r\nBelow are the " \
                   "details:\r\n\r\n\r\n1.App Name: " + "app_name" + "\r\n2.App Key: " + "app_key" + "\r\n3.Registered Date: " + "registered_date" + "\r\n4.Expiry Date: " + "expiry_date" + "\r\n\r\n\r\nUse app name and app key as headers to make calls to  services. " \
                                                                                                                                                                                             "Do not share your app key with anyone.\r\nLet us know if you face any issues.\r\n\r\nThanks "
    text = MIMEText(message_text)
    msg.attach(text)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login('xyz@gmail.com', '<password>')
    s.sendmail("xyz@gmail.com", recipients, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
except Exception as e:
    log.error("Exception in sending  email {}".format(e))
```

but its giving me the below error:

`module email has no attribute encode`

at line:

`s.sendmail("xyz@gmail.com", recipients, msg.as_bytes())`

I am not able to understand why its giving this error. I have tried only using `msg` instead of `msg.as_bytes()` but its still the same. Can anyone please point out the issue in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me.

You have assigned the module `email` when calling `msg['To'] = email`. That module must have been imported outside of the shared code (check your imports, it's probably there!). `msg.as_string()` is simply having trouble parsing the module object (since modules don't have the `encode` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. This error is because input in msg['To'] is the variable email, but you didn't create this variable.
OBS: var email needs to have the email of the person you want to send the msg to. This way, it will be possible to send the message from yours to someone's email.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).